# The `dig` and `host` commands core dump or give incomplete results

Tags: networking, 22.04

The `dig` and `host` commands give incomplete results or (sometimes) give core dumps on **Ubuntu 22.04**. Both commands are on version "**9.18.1-1ubuntu1-Ubuntu**."

When I run them like this:

```
$ dig google.com +nssearch

$ host -C google.com
```

most of the times the output is incomplete (no output or only a single line) and the other times they *core dump*. This happens on **x86_64** systems. On **aarch64** systems, they output some lines and then they *hang*.

All systems are Ubuntu 22.04 and command versions are the same as given above. Previous versions do not exhibit this problem.

Sample run:

```
$ dig google.com +nssearch 
$ dig google.com +nssearch 
$ dig google.com +nssearch 
SOA ns1.google.com. dns-admin.google.com. 444034222 900 900 1800 60 from server 216.239.38.10 in 0 ms.
$ dig google.com +nssearch 
SOA ns1.google.com. dns-admin.google.com. 444217784 900 900 1800 60 from server 216.239.32.10 in 8 ms.
$ dig google.com +nssearch 
SOA ns1.google.com. dns-admin.google.com. 444034222 900 900 1800 60 from server 216.239.34.10 in 0 ms.
dighost.c:1517: INSIST((uint_fast32_t) __extension__ ({ __auto_type __atomic_load_ptr = ((&recvcount)); __typeof__ ((void)0, *__atomic_load_ptr) __atomic_load_tmp; __atomic_load (__atomic_load_ptr, &__atomic_load_tmp, (memory_order_acquire)); __atomic_load_tmp; }) == 0) failed, back trace
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libisc-9.18.1-1ubuntu1-Ubuntu.so(+0x32083)[0x7f821fafc083]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libisc-9.18.1-1ubuntu1-Ubuntu.so(isc_assertion_failed+0x10)[0x7f821fafb570]
dig(+0x11de1)[0x55afb566fde1]
dig(+0xc7cd)[0x55afb566a7cd]
dig(+0xfdc2)[0x55afb566ddc2]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libisc-9.18.1-1ubuntu1-Ubuntu.so(isc__nm_async_readcb+0xb1)[0x7f821faeac41]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libisc-9.18.1-1ubuntu1-Ubuntu.so(isc__nm_readcb+0x9b)[0x7f821faead7b]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libisc-9.18.1-1ubuntu1-Ubuntu.so(+0x2b0d0)[0x7f821faf50d0]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libisc-9.18.1-1ubuntu1-Ubuntu.so(isc__nm_udp_read_cb+0x4a)[0x7f821faf526a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuv.so.1(+0x23e6b)[0x7f821f612e6b]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuv.so.1(+0x2511e)[0x7f821f61411e]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuv.so.1(uv_run+0x678)[0x7f821f5fdc88]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libisc-9.18.1-1ubuntu1-Ubuntu.so(+0x25eae)[0x7f821faefeae]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libisc-9.18.1-1ubuntu1-Ubuntu.so(isc__trampoline_run+0x1a)[0x7f821fb1f7ba]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x94b43)[0x7f821f6b5b43]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x126a00)[0x7f821f747a00]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Can you verify the same on your systems too?

---

#### Update

I started a related bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bind9/+bug/1970252

Comment: The same happens to me, but only wiyh the `+nssearch ` active, leave it out and the command finishes ok every time.

Comment: @SorenA Many other options give also incomplete results. Try `dig +trace google.com.` for example.